# Ttkbootstrap meter widget doc example not working

Tags: tkinter, pycharm, ttkwidgets, ttkbootstrap

I tried an example of the meter widget of ttkbootstrap and it doesn't seem to work. I copy and pasted the exact code and got this error 'AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'CUBIC'. Did you mean: 'BICUBIC'?'

This is the code

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

app = ttk.Window()

meter = ttk.Meter(
    metersize=180,
    padding=5,
    amountused=25,
    metertype="semi",
    subtext="miles per hour",
    interactive=True,
)
meter.pack()

# update the amount used directly
meter.configure(amountused = 50)

# update the amount used with another widget
entry = ttk.Entry(textvariable=meter.amountusedvar)
entry.pack(fill=X)

# increment the amount by 10 steps
meter.step(10)

# decrement the amount by 15 steps
meter.step(-15)

# update the subtext
meter.configure(subtext="loading...")

app.mainloop()
`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ttkbootstrap\gui-intro\meter\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    meter = ttk.Meter(
            ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ttkbootstrap\venv\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 718, in __init__
    self._setup_widget()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ttkbootstrap\venv\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 759, in _setup_widget
    self._draw_meter()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ttkbootstrap\venv\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 856, in _draw_meter
    img.resize((self._metersize, self._metersize), Image.CUBIC)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'CUBIC'. Did you mean: 'BICUBIC'?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There is change in `PIL.Image` that break the `ttkbootstrap` module.  You may need to install older version of `Pillow` module.

Comment: You need to download latest version 1.10.1   `python -m pip install ttkbootstrap`

Answer (score 3):

As the attribute `Image.CUBIC` is deprecated (replaced by `Image.BICUBIC`) and removed in `Pillow` v10.0.0.  Either install an older version (v9.5.0) of `Pillow` module or create the attribute explicitly before importing `ttkbootstrap` module:

```py
from PIL import Image
Image.CUBIC = Image.BICUBIC
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
...
```